# Run an application in the background of another

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin, apk

I have a problem with my android application. When I open my application I would for a method to run, from within `OnStart()`, which will pop up another and put it in the background. Then with a click event to visualize the user. Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to pop up in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an application in the background that should be shipped with your apk you need to write a service.

If the application that should run in the background is another app, not shipped by you, you can use the Android Intent system to check if it is installed and then launch it. But you can not control that application to go into the background.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , the second application that go in the background is another apk don't write by myself. practically my first application run and the secondary application runs in the background and an event click on first application i opend the secondary application . Because the second this application is open in 10 seconds